# Recover all files from SD card (not just known file extensions)

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I've run PhotoRec and it was able to recover photos, mp3s and video files from my phone's "dead" SD card.

The fact that it recovered these files would suggest that other files (Android system files, apps, application data) should also be recoverable.

The ideal situation would be to recover the complete directory structure. Assuming this were possible, how would it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find that [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) can be configured to find more files.